# Documents for Kenyan citizen travelling to the US

Tags: usa, paperwork, kenyan-citizens

I am from Kenya and I'm going to Ohio for a visit. What exactly do I need to have from the airport before my departure?

Comment: Do you have a visa? Return flight home?

Comment: No special requirement for Kenyans.

Answer (score 5):

You'll need a US visa; for a 'visit' (tourism or business) you need one of type B-1/2. If you haven't got one already, [this is the website](https://ais.usvisa-info.com/en-ke/niv) to apply from Kenya.

Once you've got the visa (which is probably the hard bit), the only other difficulty is convincing the border agent that your travel is legitimate and you intend to return home. There's no fixed requirement for any documentation to prove, but things that would help are bank statements (to indicate you've got the money to pay for your trip) and bookings for a flight home.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of your visit also matters as well as how long you intend to stay in the US. It will inform the kind of visa you'll apply for as well as what documents you will need. However, I believe we have sufficient information for you on [Timbu](https://timbu.com/kenya/visa/united-states-of-america) regardless of all these.

Comment: Welcome to [travel.se]! Since you're working for Timbu, you **must** state so explicitly in your posts if you link to it: see the [Help Center](/self/promotion).

Comment: Thank you. Please don't forget your other answer which also contains a link :)